# unrecognized characters sending email in UTF-8 in other account( non gmail)

Tags: php, utf-8, sendmail

the issue was making a nice looking html contact form design as well as the issue with accepting the user sent mail via a html table instead of a plain text mail

this is the code i am using this is my first work on php 
and it's working fine if i am using the web based mail account (gmail)

though if i move the recipent to another account(to my clients domains-email account)
it is then accepting an unregognized characters not ??????? but something like

```
×–×•×”×™ ×¤× ×™×” ×‘×§×©×¨ ×œ×‘×“×™×§×ª ×ž×™×™×œ × ×•×¡
```

as i said brefore in gmail through the browser it is perfet though 
the language in this case is hebrew as you could see in the code below in the subject or body for example

what is missing in this code so it will be ok not only in gmail web mail ?

```php
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['sender_name'];
$field_telephon = $_POST['sender_telephon'];
$field_email = $_POST['sender_mail'];
$field_Subject = $_POST['sender_Subject'];
$field_message = $_POST['sender_message'];
$StrDivOpen = "<div dir='rtl'>";
$StrDivClose = "</div>";
$StrTableOpen = "<table border='1' style='width:260px; font-family:Arial;'>";
$StrTableClose = "</table>";
$StrTrOpen ="<tr>";
$StrTdOpenHd = "<td style='background-color:#fcf7da; width:100px;'>";
$StrTdOpenCont = "<td style='background-color:#dae3a5; width:130px;'>"; 
$StrTrClose="</tr>";
$StrTdClose="</td>";
$StrBr = "<br />";

$mail_to = 'v7host@gmail.com';
$subject = 'לקוח HostDns, בשם  : '.$field_name." , נושא:  ".$field_Subject;
$body_message = $StrDivOpen.$StrTableOpen;
$body_message .= $StrTrOpen.$StrTdOpenHd.'מאת  :  '.$StrTdClose.$StrTdOpenCont.$field_name.$StrTdClose.$StrTrClose;
$body_message .= $StrTrOpen.$StrTdOpenHd.'טלפון  :    '.$StrTdClose.$StrTdOpenCont.$field_telephon.$StrTdClose.$StrTrClose;
$body_message .= $StrTrOpen.$StrTdOpenHd.'כתובת מייל  :    '.$StrTdClose.$StrTdOpenCont.$field_email.$StrTdClose.$StrTrClose;

$body_message .= "<tr><td colspan=2 style='background-color:#1cbfbf;'>תוכן ההודעה  :    </td></tr><tr><td colspan=2 style='background-color:#81c3b2;'>".$StrBr.$field_message."</td></tr></table></div>";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thanks for the post. We will contact you soon..');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Sending failed. Please send an email to v7host@gmail.com');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you change your headers to `Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`?

Comment: i will try right now , i just notest that no UTF-8 is there at all (:

Comment: give it as an answer if you like to , it is the problem (was)
(:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your encoding to UTF-8:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The current encoding you're using (ISO/IEC 8859-1) cannot handle chars from non-Western languages.